# Why would I use `case <-time.After(time.Second * 1):` over `time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)` in golang

Tags: loops, go, sleep

Looking through some code I found two ways of doing something every second:

```
for {
    fmt.Println("This is printed every second")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}
```

and

```
for {
    select {
    case <-time.After(time.Second * 1):
        fmt.Println("This is printed every second")
    }
}
```

Apart from the first one being more readable (in my opinion), I don't really understand what the advantages of one over the other is. Does anybody know?

Comment: Uh, there are some. For starters, I'd say you could have default case as well. It's sometimes really helpful but you won't get with the `time.Sleep()` way.

Comment: The advantage is exactly what you show, you can use `time.After` in a select case. The confusing thing here isn't the `time.After`, it's the pointless use of `select`

Comment: Secondly, you could have multiple tickers handled by the same `select`. If two or more tickers are invoked at once, select `picks` a random one from them.

Comment: Actually, there's a third way (which I would personally prefer using): `time.Ticker`.

Comment: @shmsr  `case <-time.After(time.Second * 1)` is not useful in the presence of a `default` clause.  In practice, the default clause will always be executed before the timer fires.

Comment: @MuffinTop: oops, yes, you're quite right, never mind. I was thinking about setting a timer for 1 second, rather than actually calling `time.After` on each trip through a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two reasons you might want to do that:

1. `time.Sleep` always blocks your current goroutine, while waiting on a channel might not if you include a default case:

```golang
    timeoutCh := time.After(time.Second)
LOOP:
    for {
        select {
        case <-timeoutCh:
            break LOOP
        default:
        }
        // do some work
    }
```

2. You can use it to add a timeout on a long-running operation.
   Let's say your long-running op will notify you on a channel. In that case a timeout on that op would be implemented like this:

```golang
    opNotifyCh := op()
    select {
    case res := <-opNotifyCh:
        fmt.Println("Op finished with result:", res)
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Op timed out")
    }
```

3. `time.After` gives you a *channel*. You can do whatever you want with it - you can pass it to a function, you can return it to a caller, you can put it in a struct - anything, really. This gives you a lot of freedom.